# Does the Parasyte story and/or manga continue after the anime?

Tags: parasyte

I've watched the *Parasyte* anime series but I haven't read the manga. The anime ends in a way that it could be the end of the story.

How is in the manga? Does the *Parasyte* story and/or manga continue after the anime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Japanese Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%AF%84%E7%94%9F%E7%8D%A3#%E5%90%84%E8%A9%B1%E3%83%AA%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%EF%BC%88%E3%82%A2%E3%83%8B%E3%83%A1%EF%BC%89), **the *Parasyte* anime adapted the *whole* 64 chapters (10 volumes) of the manga**, as such:

> 1. *stage:1*  - chapter 1-2
> 2. *stage:2*  - chapter 3-4
> 3. *stage:3*  - chapter 5-7
> 4. *stage:4*  - chapter 7-9
> 5. *stage:5*  - chapter 10-12
> 6. *stage:6*  - chapter 12-14
> 7. *stage:7*  - chapter 14-17
> 8. *stage:8*  - chapter 17-20
> 9. *stage:9*  - chapter 20-22
> 10. *stage:10* - chapter 23-25
> 11. *stage:11* - chapter 26-28
> 12. *stage:12* - chapter 29-31
> 13. *stage:13* - chapter 32-34
> 14. *stage:14* - chapter 34-36
> 15. *stage:15* - chapter 37-39
> 16. *stage:16* - chapter 40-44
> 17. *stage:17* - chapter 44-47
> 18. *stage:18* - chapter 47-49
> 19. *stage:19* - chapter 50-52
> 20. *stage:20* - chapter 53-55
> 21. *stage:21* - chapter 55-57
> 22. *stage:22* - chapter 57-60
> 23. *stage:23* - chapter 61-62
> 24. *final stage* - chapter 63-64

The storyline and the content are basically the same with most modifications related to cosmetic only (e.g. time period and character appearance).

However, there's a new spin-off manga called [*Parasyte Reversi*](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=148828) which debuted in March 2018.